# Xubuntu 18.04 tiny cursor on hi-dpi screen

Tags: xubuntu, cursor

I recently installed Xubuntu 18.04 on a DELL XPS 15 with hi-dpi screen, and no matter what I can't make the mouse cursor larger. It's currently so small I can't see it. How can I set the cursor size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad, choose tab Theme.

[image: cursor settings]

Comment: Unfortunately you will might still have some problems. I have a Dell XPS 13 with same issue and snaps are a problem because they don't respect your theme/settings. Similarly for applications under wine. Canonical really need to fix this before going all-out for snaps, high DPI screens are only going to get more and more common.