# Xubuntu 20.04 unable to change cursor size

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, cursor, i3-wm, cursor-theme

I recently updated from Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 on my Dell XPS 15 with hi-dpi screen and I'm unable to change cursor size. I'm using XFCE with i3 as window manager. So far I've tried:

- Adding `Xcursor.size: 64` to `~/.Xresources`
- Updating cursor size in "Mouse and Touchpad" > "Theme"

I was able to scale the cursor size in 18.04 using (2) ([Xubuntu 18.04 tiny cursor on hi-dpi screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031183/xubuntu-18-04-tiny-cursor-on-hi-dpi-screen)), but it doesn't work on 20.04.

How do I change cursor size on Xubuntu 20.04?

```
~ $ cat .Xresources
Xcursor.theme:  DMZ-White
Xcursor.size:   200
~ $ cat .xinitrc
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
~ $ cat .xprofile
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
~ $ xrdb -query
*customization: -color
xscreensaver.Dialog.Button.background:  #444
xscreensaver.Dialog.Button.foreground:  #EDEDFF
xscreensaver.Dialog.background: #202020
xscreensaver.Dialog.bodyFont:   -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.borderWidth:        0
xscreensaver.Dialog.bottomShadowColor:  #202024
xscreensaver.Dialog.buttonFont: -*-dina-bold-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.dateFont:   -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.foreground: #EDEDED
xscreensaver.Dialog.headingFont:        -*-dina-bold-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.internalBorderWidth:        24
xscreensaver.Dialog.labelFont:  -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.shadowThickness:    2
xscreensaver.Dialog.text.background:    #444
xscreensaver.Dialog.text.foreground:    #EDEDFF
xscreensaver.Dialog.topShadowColor:     #202024
xscreensaver.Dialog.unameFont:  -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.dateFormat:        %I:%M%P %a %b %d, %Y
xscreensaver.passwd.passwdFont: -*-dina-bold-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.passwd.thermometer.background:     #202020
xscreensaver.passwd.thermometer.foreground:     #A9B7C4
xscreensaver.passwd.thermometer.width:  8
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.lcdfilter:  lcddefault
Xft.dpi:        239
Xcursor.theme:  default
Xcursor.size:   200
Xcursor.theme_core:     1
```

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I am under gnome, so some of the items below are best guesses.*

Some others also described occasional weird behavior.
So I will: 1) Give *possible* solutions. 2) Ask you to post some info. 3) Give sources.

### Possible Solutions

Perhaps you already applied some of these.

1. Reboot (trivial)
2. [Execute](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343419/137608) (you may need `xorg-xrdb` as per the not-so-old reference; in my system `dpkg -S /usr/bin/xrdb` returns `x11-xserver-utils: /usr/bin/xrdb`)

   ```
   $ xrdb ~/.Xresources
   ```

   to load the configuration.
3. [Add](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes#X_resources) `xrdb ~/.Xresources` to `~/.xinitrc` or `.xprofile`.
4. [Use](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes#XFCE) [`xconf-query`](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query) ("In *most* cases, any modifications will immediately be propagated to respective applications.")

   ```
   $ xfconf-query --channel xsettings --property /Gtk/CursorThemeSize --set <cursor_theme_size>
   ```
5. Set/modify in `~/.Xresources` also `Xcursor.theme: <cursor-theme>` to see if has any effect. Combine with setting `Xcursor.size`. Cursor size may [respond differently](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/cannot-change-mouse-cursor-size-in-xfce/62573/5) with other cursor themes.
   I am not sure this is exactly the same [as in](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031188/226614)
   *Settings* -> *Mouse and Touchpad* -> *Theme* -> *Cursor size*.
   Perhaps one is equivalent to the other, plus `xrdb ...` to load the configuration...
6. [Set environment variable `XCURSOR_SIZE`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes#Environment_variable) for a specific application.
7. Try changing the cursor size with the default Window Manager.

### Requested extra info

1. Post the output of

   ```
   $ xrdb -query
   ```
2. Which cursor theme are you using (not all support changing the cursor size)? Which is the size you are having, and what you want to have?

### Sources

1. https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12578
2. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=307516
3. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes
4. https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/cannot-change-mouse-cursor-size-in-xfce/62573/5
5. https://www.funtoo.org/Package:Xfce4-settings

Comment: None of this worked!! I've added `xrdb -query` output in my original message.

Comment: @sinan - What did you get after:
1) `xfconf-query ... --set ...`, `xrdb ~/.Xresources` and `xrdb -query`?
2) changing `Xcursor.theme` to something different than the default, `xfconf-query ... --set ...`, `xrdb ~/.Xresources` and `xrdb -query`?
I guess you should tinker a bit with some combinations.
Did you manage to install `xrdb`? What package owned it?

Comment: I show outputs of xrdb commands in your answer, so clearly I have it installed. I will try changing the theme today.

Comment: @sinan - Right... what package owns it?
Bear in mind that you might need some further actions for the changes to take place. I have found not-very-consistent information on this, but what I posted and links provided give some options.